# Program to automate form field entry and result checking of webpage

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, web-scraping, webbrowser-control

I am trying to create a program in C# (maybe using WinForms) which will enter a licence number into a form field of a specific [website](https://www.onegov.nsw.gov.au/PublicRegister/#/publicregister/search/Security) and validate whether or not the licence number is a currently valid licence.

I am unsure as to where to start, as I can't even find the form field id in the source code of the website, and am unsure what technologies the website uses.

Additionally, the purpose of this program will be to enter a list of license numbers and return the names and validation status of each license. Datasource being the website.

Any information on how to go about this would be much appreciated, I am an intermediate C# developer - having mostly worked in ASP.Net, though feel Winforms may be better suited for this project.

Kind Regards

Comment: Let me know if you find the idea helpful or you have any question :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [`WebBrowser`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2te2y1x6(v=vs.110).aspx) control:

1. You can load the page using `webBrowser1.Navigate("url of site")`
2. Find elements in page using `webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("buttonid")` also you can iterate over `HtmlElement` of `webBrowser1.Document.Body.All` and check for example `element.GetAttribute("value") == "some vaule"` to find it.
3. Set value for element using `element.InnerText ="some value"` or `element.SetAttribute("value", "some value")`
4. Submit your form by invoking the submit of form or click of its submit button using  `element.InvokeMember("method")`

### Example

For example, if you browse google and look at page source, you will see name of search text box is "q" and name of the form that contains the search box is "f", so you can write this codes to automate search.

1. Create a form with name `BrowserSample`.
2. From toolbox, drag a `WebBrowser` and drop on form.
3. Hanfdle `Load` event of form and navigate to google.
4. Handle `DocumentCompleted` event of `webBrowser1` and find `f` and find `q` and set `InnerText` of `q` and invoke submit of `f`. This event fires after the navigation and document load completed.
5. In a real application add required null checking.

**Code:**

```
private void BrowserSample_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.webBrowser1.Navigate("https://www.google.com/");
}

void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    //Because submitting f causes navigation
    //to pervent a loop, we check the url of navigation 
    //and if it's different from google url, return
    if (e.Url.AbsoluteUri != "https://www.google.com/")
        return;
    var f = this.webBrowser1.Document.Body.All.GetElementsByName("f")
                .Cast<HtmlElement>()
                .FirstOrDefault();

    var q = f.All.GetElementsByName("q")
                .Cast<HtmlElement>()
                .FirstOrDefault();

    q.InnerText = "C# Webbrowser Control";
    f.InvokeMember("submit");
}
```

If you execute the program, it first navigate to google and then shows search result:

[image]

**In your special case**

Since the site loads content using ajax, then you should make a delay in `DocumentCompleted`:

```
async void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Url.AbsoluteUri != "https://www.onegov.nsw.gov.au/PublicRegister/#/publicregister/search/Security")
        return;

    await Task.Delay(5000);
    var f = this.webBrowser1.Document.Body.All.GetElementsByName("searchForm")
                .Cast<HtmlElement>()
                .FirstOrDefault();

    var q = f.All.GetElementsByName("searchText")
                .Cast<HtmlElement>()
                .FirstOrDefault();

    q.InnerText = "123456789";
    f.InvokeMember("submit");
}
```

Don't forget to add `using System.Threading.Tasks;` or if you use .Net 4.0 you simple can use `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000)` and remove async/await.

Comment: I seem to be getting a null pointer from 1.

Also the element doesn't have an ID, only a Name, and for some reason there is no GetElementByName ? :(, Also 'webBrowser1.Document.Body.All' doesn't seem to have an 'All' property.

Comment: @LeighCooper I updated the answer and added a working sample.

Comment: weird anomaly, when I try `webBrowser1.Document.Body.All`, sometimes I only get 6 tags, other times I get 61 or so...

I tried the above because:

`var f = this.webBrowser1.Document.Body.All.GetElementsByName("f")
                .Cast<HtmlElement>()
                .FirstOrDefault();
    var q = f.All.GetElementsByName("q")
                .Cast<HtmlElement>()
                .FirstOrDefault();`

was causing null pointer errors.

Comment: @LeighCooper Did you tried my sample code and received a different result than the screenshot I posted?

Comment: Your code works, I had to change some things - because Google localizes the address. Just isn't working for the website I'm trying to work on :(.

Comment: @LeighCooper It's because the site uses ajax to load content. you can make a delay and then do the job. I edited the post for your case.

Comment: Awesome thanks! Works - one more issue though, I can't InvokeMember("submit") on an anchor tag.

`<a href="" data-ng-click="vm.form.search.go()" class="button expand trade-search-icon"><i class="icon-ios-search-strong"></i></a>`

Is there any way to invoke that javascript?

Comment: @LeighCooper Yes, I think you find that link and `Invoke("click")`. You can play with  `this.webBrowser1.Document.Body.All.Cast<HtmlElement>()` and apply any linq query you want. you can find objects based on any attribues.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the website uses JSON POSTs. If you have FireFox open Developer -> Network and look at the "PerformSearch" entry. That will tell you everything you need to know as far as what the website is expecting in a POST request so you can read the response.