# How to press a login button of a website programmatically

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I am loading a website into a `WebBrowser` in a winform. I wish to login using a log and pass automatically via vb.net

I have the following code executing once the page loads

```
 WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("e").SetAttribute("value", "email@address")
                WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("p").SetAttribute("value", "password")
                WebBrowser1.Document.Forms(0).InvokeMember("submit")
```

I am able to fill in the boxes that need to contain the Log and pass but I am not able to fire off the login button of the webpage automatically. After research I am confident that I replicated the sample I found properly but obviously there is an issue. The 'button' isn't pressed because I don't get anything happening. When I press the website login manually it logs in correctly using the data that I filled in .

the webpage link is https://www.weatherzone.com.au/customise.jsp

and the relevant source data is below

```
 <form action="/customise.jsp" method="post" style="width: 75%; text-align: left;">
  <div style="margin-bottom: 1em;">
    <label for="e">Enter your email address:</label>
    <input style="width: 95%;" type="text" name="e" id="e" /><br />
  </div>

  <div style="margin-bottom: 1em;">
    <label for="p">Enter your password:</label>
    <input style="width: 95%;" type="password" name="p" id="p" /><br />
  </div>

  <div style="margin-bottom: 1em;">
    <input type="checkbox" name="rmbr" id="rmbr" value="1" />
    <label for="rmbr" style="display: inline;">Remember me (check this box if you are a regular user of this computer)</label>
  </div>

  <div style="text-align: right; margin-top: 20px; padding-top: 10px; border-top: 1px solid silver;">
    <input class="submit btn" type="submit" name="target" value="login" />
  </div>

  <input type="hidden" name="dest" value="/" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I applied this logic:

- Put the code in a `DocumentCompleted` event to run the code after the document completed.
- The `DocumentCompleted` also raises when an iframe document completed, so to get rid of iframes use a criteria like comparing `e.Url` with the base url know.
- Find the submit button by name and click on it.

And it worked properly. It redirected to the same url and showed a red not authenticated message.

**Code:**

```
Private Sub WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(sender As Object, e As WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted
    If (e.Url.ToString().StartsWith("https://www.weatherzone.com.au")) Then
        WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("e").SetAttribute("value", "email@address.com")
        WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("p").SetAttribute("value", "password")
        WebBrowser1.Document.All().GetElementsByName("target").Cast(Of HtmlElement).First().InvokeMember("click")
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Me.WebBrowser1.Navigate("https://www.weatherzone.com.au/customise.jsp")
End Sub
```

To make the code more stable, add required null checkings.

Comment: thanks, it was the 'click member that I didn't have correct, with your code I now log in perfectly. Greatly appreciated!

Comment: You also may find this Q/A [Program to automate form field entry and result checking of webpage](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32934920/3110834) helpful.