# C# log into site without ID

Tags: c#, html, winforms

I am trying to create a function which will auto-login someone into a site.

The frm.Login and frm.Password is there because I am importing strings from another form. That other form is where they type in their credentials.

**Disclaimer:**
I do NOT have access to this site!

**The HTML code**

```
<input type="email" required="" size="21" name="email"> //email
<input type="password" required="" name="password" size="21"> //password
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Sign in"> //button to sign in.
```

**My Attempt**

```
Form3 frm = new Form3();
frm.ShowDialog();
webBrowser1.Navigate("examplesite.php");

webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input")
            .GetElementsByName("email")[0]
            .SetAttribute("Value", frm.Login);

webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input")
            .GetElementsByName("password")[0]
            .SetAttribute("Value", frm.Password);

ClickButton("submit");
```

**The Code for ClickButton**

```
public void ClickButton(string type)
{
    var button = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("submit")
             .Cast<HtmlElement>()
             .FirstOrDefault(m => m.GetAttribute("type") == type);
    if (button != null)
        button.InvokeMember("click");
}
```

> Error: An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in Test.exe Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>
> Line that gives error: `webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input").GetElementsByName("email")[0].SetAttribute("Value", frm.Login);`

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How do I pass the strings from my winforms application into the site's login and password textboxes...

Comment: once you navigate to the site, you need to wait the site fully loaded. right now, you immediately set the textbox value which may fail. The error is exactly what I think. webBrowser has an event for document loaded.

Comment: You will want to wait with the DocumentCompleted event: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documentcompleted(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Take a look at this example: [how to press a login button of a website programaticaly](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34351668/3110834)

Comment: @Crowcoder I looked into DocumentCompleted event. And I fixed that issue. But, the button is not pressing. Thanks though! The textboxes work!

Comment: change GetElementsByTagName("button") to GetElementsByName("submit")

Comment: Still not clicking it...

Comment: I found a new answer for it. nvm. That button code was off.

Answer (score 0):

Code used to click the button. It takes the "Sign in" value and clicks it

```
 foreach (HtmlElement el in elCol)
                {
                    if (el.GetAttribute("value").Equals("Sign in"))
                    {
                        el.InvokeMember("click");
                    }
                }
```