# Why when i try to click on a web site button using webBrowser it's not clicking?

Tags: c#, html, .net, winforms

Inside a button click event i did

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    webBrowser4.DocumentCompleted += webBrowser4_DocumentCompleted;
    webBrowser4.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
    webBrowser4.Navigate("http://www.tapuz.co.il/forums/addmsg/393");                                              
}
```

Then in the DocumentCompleted

```
bool addmessage = false;
void webBrowser4_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (this.webBrowser4.Document != null && webBrowser4.ReadyState == WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
    {
        if (addmessage == false)
        {
            HtmlElementCollection items = webBrowser4.Document.GetElementsByTagName("div");
            foreach (HtmlElement item in items)
            {
                if (item.GetAttribute("className") == "elements")
                {
                    webBrowser4.Document.GetElementById("ctl00_RightMainContent_txt_subject").InnerText = "עדכוני ערב למחוק";
                    webBrowser4.Document.GetElementById("ctl00_RightMainContent_submitAddress_p_submitButtom").InvokeMember("Click");
                    addmessage = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Inside the page when i make Inspect Element on the subjest box i see:

```
<div class="elements" style="position: relative">
    <input name="ctl00$RightMainContent$txt_subject" type="text" maxlength="60" id="ctl00_RightMainContent_txt_subject" tabindex="1" class="subjectField">
    <span class="addEmoticon" onclick="showMyIcons('ctl00_RightMainContent_txt_subject')"></span>
</div>
```

When I make on send message button Inspect Element i see

```
<div id="ctl00_RightMainContent_submitAddress_p_submitButtom" class="elements">
    <button class="btn_send mianBtn btn opensans" tabindex="3">פרסם</button>
    <button class="btn_showBeforesend subBtn btn" tabindex="4">תצוגה מקדימה</button>
</div>
```

This is my screenshots:

The first screenshot is how I see the website in the `WebBrowser` control:
All buttons text and text boxes not in place.

[image: In webbrowser]

This is how it is in the web site in Chrome or IE as it should be:

[image: In website original]

Comment: could you please be more specific about what you mean by "it's not clicking"?

Comment: Cindy i mean that after it's doing the line with the "Click" it dosen't send on the site the message. It's not clicking the send button. I'm not sure about the line before it with the txt_subject and the InnerText but i know using a breakpoint it's getting and doing both lines in the code but in fact nothing happen on the site.

Comment: I checked now and i see that the first line webBrowser4.Document.GetElementById("ctl00_RightMainContent_txt_subject").InnerText = "עדכוני ערב למחוק"; is working. I see the text in the site in the subject textbox. The problem is with the second line with the "Click" i tried also "click" but it's not sending not clicking the button on the site.

Comment: @DanielHamutel You may find these answers helpful: [how to press a login button of a website programaticaly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34350906/how-to-press-a-login-button-of-a-website-programaticaly) and [Program to automate form field entry and result checking of webpage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32934920/program-to-automate-form-field-entry-and-result-checking-of-webpage). There you will see how to use `DocumentCompleted` event, find some elements, fill inputs and click buttons or submit forms.

Comment: Reza i found in the second link one helpful thing is the checking if the Url's the same so i know when the website loaded complete. But i can't find what i'm doing wrong with the button click. I didn't change other then that much in my code. The GetAttribute is still checking if the className is "elements" and then the first line of GetElementById is fine i see the text "עדכוני ערב למחוק" in the correct field but the second line of GetElementById that should make the button click is not working.

Comment: Reza i tried to add item.InvokeMember("Click"); i also tried to change in both lines Click to click tried submit. But i'm missing something with this button.

Comment: This is is the source-view of the page: view-source:http://www.tapuz.co.il/forums/addmsg/393 and on line 1329 you can see the button i need to make click on.

Comment: Why you are clicking on `div`? You should click on one of buttons in the `ctl00_RightMainContent_submitAddress_p_submitButtom` div.

Comment: By the way, when you want to mention someone in comment, use @ before the username like @RezaAghaei to notify the user, otherwise the user will not be notified about the message and maybe he never see your messages.

Comment: @RezaAghaei Thanks i didn't kniw about the notify. Could you show me please the code of the clicking, How it sohlud be like ? I messed it up i guess

Comment: There are 2 buttons in the div, which one you want to click? `פרסם` or `>תצוגה מקדימה`?

Comment: By the way, when you find some helpful question or answer, you can kindly vote for them. It's not compulsory at all, but it makes the post more useful for future readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are clicking on div while you should click on a button.

For example, if you want to click on `פרסם` button in the below structure, you should find the button and then click on it.

**Structure:**

```
<div id="ctl00_RightMainContent_submitAddress_p_submitButtom" class="elements">
    <button class="btn_send mianBtn btn opensans" tabindex="3">פרסם</button>
    <button class="btn_showBeforesend subBtn btn" tabindex="4">תצוגה מקדימה</button>
</div>
```

**An example of how to find the button:**

If you are sure the button is the only element having `class="btn_send mianBtn btn opensans"` you can find it directly, but if its possible to have some other buttons having that exact class in document, you should find the button based on the `div`:

```
var div = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("ctl00_RightMainContent_submitAddress_p_submitButtom");
if (div != null)
{
    var button = div.All.Cast<HtmlElement>().Where(x =>
        !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.GetAttribute("class")) &&
        x.GetAttribute("class").Contains("btn_send")).FirstOrDefault();

    if (button != null)
        button.InvokeMember("click");
    else
        MessageBox.Show("Button not found.");
}
```

Also you when you find the div, you can use this code to find the button:

```
var button = div.All[0];
```

**To load website correctly in Web Browser control:**

It seems you need to disable compatibility settings for web browser control. Follow instructions [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ee330730(v=vs.85).aspx#browser_emulation) to disable the setting using registry.

I applied settings in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` to make it work:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION
```

and this values:

```
"YourApplicationFileName.exe"=dword:00002af9`
"YourApplicationFileName.vshost.exe"=dword:00002af9`
```

Comment: I'm getting button null the messagebox that show "Button not found." Should i put it inside some loop ? I added it to the DocumentCompleted event and used break point and the button is null.

Comment: Put the code in `DocumentCompleted`, also make sure the event is fired for your desired address, you can check `e.Url.the event AbsoluteUri` to make sure the event is not for a frame or something else.

Comment: I did. Yet the button is null. Strange. I checked in the page source view and this is the right id "ctl00_RightMainContent_submitAddress_p_submitButtom" not sure why the button is null.

Comment: Did it find the `div`? What are elements in `div.All`?

Comment: In div.All i don't see elements property but i see in All that there two items the first have many properties i entered DomElement and saw btn_send mianBtn btn opensans as className. Yes i found the div "ctl00_RightMainContent_submitAddress_p_submitButtom" in the page source-view

Comment: So you are very close to the answer. The criteria `!string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.GetAttribute("class")) &&
        x.GetAttribute("class").Contains("btn_send")` should work, but you can also use `div.All[0]`

Comment: Using div.All[0] it's getting to the "click" but does nothing in the site. Also if i click inside the webBrowser window on my own on the button it does nothing. But if i click on it in the website using chrome it's sending the message. Strange why it's not taking effect from inside the webBrowser.

Comment: If you open the address in Internet Explorer does the button work properly?

Comment: I checked now in chrome and it's working. Another strange thing is that in the webBrowser i see all the buttons and textboxes and the text not in place as it is in chrome and should be in the original site. I will add a screenshot of what i see in the webBrowser and how it is in the original site to my question. Same in IE it's working fine.

Comment: I found that if in the webbrowser i navigate first to the main site: "http://www.tapuz.co.il/forums/forumpage/393/%D7%98%D7%91%D7%A2_%D7%95%D7%9E%D7%96%D7%92_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%95%D7%99%D7%A8/%D7%9E%D7%96%D7%92_%D7%94%D7%90%D7%95%D7%95%D7%99%D7%A8 then i see everything fine then there i can click on the button to add a new message(הוספת הודעה) when i click on it and it's getting to the add message page then it's getting mess buttons and texts not in place. I can't figure out why the main site is fine in the webbrowser but the add message page is a mess.

Comment: I think it is a compatibility problem. The question is now **Why the site doesn't load correctly using WebBroswer control while loads correctly in internet explorer**

Comment: Probably you need to disable compatibility settings for web browser control. Take a look at [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ee330730(v=vs.85).aspx#browser_emulation)

Comment: I can confirm that this is a compatibility problem and can be solved by disabling the setting using registry but in current user key not in local machine key. As I did it using `[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION]
"YourApplicationFileName.exe"=dword:00002af9`

Comment: Wow i will try it now.

Comment: I need to replace it with something the "my app.exe"=dword:00002af9 or to add it there as a new value ,key or something else ? I'm in the right place in the registry. What i have in this location is: devenv.exe REG_DWORD 0x0000270f (9999)

Comment: Disable you mean to delete it ?

Comment: No don't remove anything. just add the key with value (decimal: 11001) for ie 11. with your app name.

Comment: If you want to use this feature in debug mode, add yourapp.vshost.exe too

Comment: My god it's working. I will add also the vshost. Wow thank you very much for the help.

Comment: Another point, instead of `while (e.Url.AbsoluteUri != webBrowser4.Url.AbsoluteUri)` simply use an `if` statement. You don't need to use `while`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98952/discussion-between-daniel-hamutel-and-reza-aghaei).