# How to simulate a link being clicked through C# Windows Forms App, that locally generates a file?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am writing an application that analyzes multiple .csv files and gives an overview of all the data.

The csv files I use are created when you click on a link at the host website, which I do not own, but have access to an API.

Looking at the Network tab, when the button is clicked there is no file being generated/sent over the network which makes me believe the files are generated locally, if that is possible.

Is there a way for me to get these same results, through C#? I have attempted at using the `client.DownloadFile()` with the url of the link, but to no avail.

Any tips/resources are appreciated!

Comment: You are talking about scraping the site but you also say you have API access. Do they expose an API that does what you want?

Comment: I don't really want to scrape the site if I don't have to, I just want a way of downloading/generating the 4 .csv files I need automatically, instead of having to manually download each one. 

It does not, I have messaged the developers of the site asking for a possible addition to the API.

Comment: You should be able to recreate the request that triggers when you click the button. What does the request look like in the network trace?

Comment: As I mention in my post, when I click the label there is no activity in the network trace. Looking at the source code, the section with the label/link is Javascript, so I am unable to see what the href actually is.

Comment: You said no file being generated,  you didn't say no activity. The javascript probably triggers an XHR request which you can also see the details of.

Comment: Ah, my apologies. I was looking under 'all' and there was no activity. I tried again looking at XHR, and no activity there either.

Comment: You need to simulate click on the link using `WebBrowser. There are a lot of examples around, including [Program to automate form field entry and result checking of webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32934920/3110834)

Comment: Anyway, your question in the current format cannot be answered because we don't have enough information to reproduce the problem. Please consider posting a [MCVE].

Comment: Unless all the data is already stored in local storage there must be some kind of request being initiated. Are you using the "Preserve log" or equivalent option in the browser tools?

Comment: I know it is very confusing to me as well. Yes I had "Preserve" log enabled, I am able to see all the requests up until I click the label to generate the file, when I click nothing on the network tab pops up.

Comment: @Crowcoder This may actually just be an issue with the browser I am using, I downloaded a file from a different site and Chrome did not show any network activity. I will try again with Firefox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We would need more information in order to accurately help you.
For the time being - your issue at this stage I assume is the actual download of the CSV files - you don't want to have to manually acquire the files, because you want your application to do it auto-magically.

When you click the link in the website - does it generate it, and then you have another link to click to download?
Or is it one click to generate and download?

What is the website - and do you have any URL for its API reference?
Generally speaking - if the site provides an API, then you would not access the file with the typical URL that you see in your browser.
You would use the API to authenticate and then access your account / file resources.

This could be in the form of

```
MyAPI.Auth auth  = new Auth("API-KEY-HERE");
var myFiles[] = MyAPI.Files.GetAllFiles(auth,"/online/Folder");
foreach(var file in myFiles){
     //Do something
     file.Download("/some/folder");
}
```

Without knowing more about the API or the site in question, there are too many information gaps for us to advise you with any certainty.
My assumption here is that the API of the Website will provide access to the file in question.
Otherwise - you may be able to access the file via its web-url, but you will likely need authentication cookies in order to download it.

Comment: When I click the link, it automatically generates it in my chrome browser as if it had downloaded, but under the network tab there is no activity.

I am currently using their API for other functionality, but at the moment their API only supports returning 2 of the .csv files I need, and not the other 2.

Comment: If it is indeed generated locally, then you would need to examine the sources tab of chrome to see what javascript libraries are present.
If it is indeed generated locally, you may be able to borrow the javascript libraries, and then load them into your own WebBrowser control in a C# WinForms application, and trigger the javascript yourself.

Comment: I am not sure if I can post screenshots here, but [this is](https://i.imgur.com/OonTS3y.png) the code responsible for the label that generates the text file, as well as the data displayed of the file.